# what is foo? I have seen it in many CSS and Web designing examples

Tags: css

What is foo? I have seen it in many CSS and Web designing examples usually as a CSS class.

Comment: [Google is your friend](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foobar).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

see 'foo' entry in jargon file.

http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/F/foo.html

esp. 2. [very common] Used very generally as a sample name for absolutely anything, esp. programs and files (esp. scratch files).

Comment: Interestingly weird, I should say!

Answer (score 6):

A "metasyntactic variable" - in other words, it serves the same purpose as `example.com`, usually to illustrate "this is where *your* variable will be, whatever it is named".

See the Jargon File for common (and less common) such variables: http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/M/metasyntactic-variable.html

Answer (score 4):

> The terms foobar, foo, bar, baz and qux are sometimes used as placeholder names (also referred to as metasyntactic variables) in computer programming or computer-related documentation

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foobar#Usage_in_code).

When working with IE6, sometimes it is [FUBAR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FUBAR).

Answer (score 2):

A standard token. "Foo" and "Bar" are names for variables, classes, whatever that have no meaning and are often used in examples.

Answer (score 1):

It is just a variable or something like that.
It is used as a demo or dummy or as an example to for explaining codes.
Eg:- in maths we usually say x,y,z or a,b,c ....etc

Answer (score 0):

It's a metasyntactic value with some sarcastic wit. Foobar references FUBAR which is a military term for 'F'd up beyond all recognition.'